# trigger to congratulate people

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, group-policy

I have a task that I've been working on for 2 weeks now and I can't complete it. I need to find a way to congratulate people who are celebrating their birthday today on behalf of the company, and do it when the person first logs in, even if it's a few days later.

1. I created a powerpoint (.ppsm) for each user.
2. I created a task in group policy.
3. I created a trigger for each employee (with task activation date)
4. I set the trigger to activate only for a specific user on a specific PC.
5. I let the task live for a few days (e.g. -5)
6. When the trigger is activated, powerpoint will open.

This is where the problem comes in, for example, during the task's active period, every time the user logs in - powerpoint is activated, and this is annoying. This should only be done the first time you log in.

And, of course, it would be better to make a single powerpoint with an absolute variable in the name, which will change depending on the logged in user.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem easier or has a solution to what I described above, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

OKay, honestly, a sudden birthday powerpoint when trying to log in is the *last* thing I'd want – both as the employee and as the person answering the inevitable helpdesk calls... Please tell me at least there's no sound effects.

* * *

Make your GPO run a script that checks whether a "flag file" or "marker file" exists that indicates whether the script has already been run this year – if it does, immediately exit; and if it doesn't exist, display the greeting and *create* the file. This is a general solution for all kinds of "only run once" tasks.

A good location for such marker files is the user's `${env:AppData}\` folder. Since this is Windows, a Registry value in HKCU would also work, though working with files may still be easier.

Since this is a yearly task, the script should also store the current year in the file, and compare it on startup. (Another option is to put the year in the file name, e.g. `shown_birthday_${year}`, though it adds some clutter.)

Since this task isn't a "must succeed even if it takes a few retries" kind of script, make sure to test how it errors, so that it should still create the file even if it fails to start PowerPoint for some reason, and not annoy the user with error messages until it expires.

Comment: I tried to explain that it would be more logical for HR to send an email, but I was not heard

Comment: I honestly don't understand how to interconnect the script with the procedure I described above.
How do I stop activating triggers in my policy when such a file is found?

Comment: You don't, that was not the point of this post. The point was to put the logic in the script itself and not in the trigger, i.e. make the activation "harmless" rather than prevent it completely.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to set the task to run once at an early hour
in the morning.

That way, the task should wait for the user to logon later on.